# Where to run "dotnet ef scaffold" for a new console application?

Tags: entity-framework-core, console-application

Trying to create a new console application in Visual Studio accessing an existing SQL Server database. Would like to use EF Core to scaffold models from the database.

MicroSoft's "Getting Started" instructions seem way off. They suggest using NuGet console and running 
**Scaffold-DbContext "Server=...."  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**

This does nothing.

One source suggests running "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=....", but this errors out with:

**CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (No executable f...and "dotnet-ef":String) [], RemoteException**

If I'm running dotnet ef shouldn't I been a command prompt, rather than PM console? But in which folder? Running in the project folder errors out with **no executable found matching "dotnet-ef"**. Note that this is a console application (not ASP) and does not have Project.json, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Did you install EF Nuget Package ?

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework

Comment: I thought I had, following the instructions on the site, but when I went and did it (again), they worked. So thanks for pointing it out.